# How to change between Roboto font variants within the document?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use the [Roboto font](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/roboto) in one of my documents. I can load it like this:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
```

This font supports these variants: `regular, bold, medium, black, light, thin` which can be activated by specifying them in the package options, like:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault, thin]{roboto}
```

But how can I change between the variants within my document? Most of the time I need `light` (so I load the package with the `light` option), but sometimes I need `thin`. How can I change between them in my document?

Comment: `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{t}\selectfont` when you want to use Thin.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}

\begin{document}

This is the Light version

\begingroup
\fontseries{t}\selectfont

This is the Thin version

\endgroup

This is the Light version again

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, are these `\fontseries{}` values specific per font or are they always the same (given a font provides these variants at all)?

Comment: @FooBar There are the standard ones `m`, `b` or `bx`, but for others one has to look in the package.

Comment: I think what you refer to as _light_ is actually _medium_ aka the default.  Oh, wait -- once one used option `thin` it is as you claim.  My bad.