# Change Roboto Medium to Roboto Regular variants

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use the Roboto font in one of my documents. I load it like this:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
```

It should support variants regular, bold, medium, black, light, thin.

I need to change between Regular and Medium variant, but it doesn't seem to work for me. I tried both

```
\usepackage[sfdefault, regular]{roboto}
\usepackage[sfdefault, medium]{roboto}
```

and they look the same; besides resolving this still doesn't offer solution to using BOTH in one document. Any thoughts what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you really need to use pdflatex? More flexibility is provided by xe-/lualatex and fontspec.

Comment: I was already checking it out, but yes, I need pdflatex.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288959/how-to-change-between-roboto-font-variants-within-the-document help?

Comment: Tried the exact same thing with medium/regular, doesn't work. Maybe a bug in the package...

Answer (score 1):

The `medium` option changes the bold font (`\bfseries`):

[image]

[image]

If you want to change the normal font (`\mdseries`) use the options light or thin.